# How can i output this kind of array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this kind of array in PHP and i dont know how to output to web.

```
$numbers = [
[76 ,111 ,114 ,101 ,69 ,110 ,105 ,112 ,115],
[117,109,120,100,111],
[108 ,111, 114, 110, 115, 99, 116, 110, 97, 109, 101],
[116, 44, 110, 99, 111, 110, 101, 101, 99, 116, 101, 116, 117],
[114, 110, 97, 100, 108, 112, 105, 115, 99],
[105, 110, 103, 110, 101, 101, 105, 116, 44, 110, 115],
[101, 100, 110, 110, 111, 110, 101],
[105, 117, 115, 109, 116, 100, 110, 116, 101],
[109, 112, 33, 114, 110]];
```

What i tried:
`Echo $numbers;
print_r ($numbers);
foreach($numbers as $value)....`

I already end this project. It was for university but now i want to make a better design for this . So i just need to know how to ,,echo,, those values on website as they are in that array!

`foreach($numbers as $value){
    echo $value . "<br>";
} //this is what i tried last time`

Comment: What happened with all your current attempts?

Comment: You need foreach inside another foreach

Comment: Web PHP Errors.

Comment: If you are getting errors please always include those in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Dharman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839439/dharman) for comment about foreach in foreach :D

```
foreach($numbers as $line){
    foreach($line as $value){
        echo $value . " ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

This is the code for my question!